# How do I return an ifstream back to the beginning of a line that was just read in C++?

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

After I read a line from a file using ifstream, is there a way to bring the stream back to the beginning of the line I just read, conditionally?

```
using namespace std;
//Some code here
ifstream ifs(filename);
string line;
while(ifs >> line)
{
   //Some code here related to the line I just read

   if(someCondition == true)
   {
    //Go back to the beginning of the line just read
   }
   //More code here
}
```

So if someCondition is true, the next line read during the next while-loop iteration will be the same line I just read right now. Otherwise, the next while-loop iteration will use the following line in the file. If you need further clarification, please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE #1**

So I tried the following:

```
while(ifs >> line)
{
   //Some code here related to the line I just read
   int place = ifs.tellg();
   if(someCondition == true)
   {
    //Go back to the beginning of the line just read
    ifs.seekg(place);
   }
   //More code here
}
```

But it doesn't read the same line again when the condition is true. Is an integer an acceptable type here?

**UPDATE #2: The Solution**

There was an error in my logic. Here is the corrected version that works as I want it to for any of those that are curious:

```
int place = 0;
while(ifs >> line)
{
   //Some code here related to the line I just read

   if(someCondition == true)
   {
    //Go back to the beginning of the line just read
    ifs.seekg(place);
   }
  place = ifs.tellg();
   //More code here
}
```

The call to tellg() was moved to the end because you need to seek to the beginning of the previously read line. The first time around I called tellg() and then called seekg() before the stream even changed, which is why it seemed like nothing changed (because it really hadn't). Thank you all for your contributions.

Comment: Use tellg() to get the stream position before you read the line and seekg() to set the stream position to the position you saved before.

Comment: By the way, ifs >> to string is not getting lines, but words. Use std::getline

Comment: Thanks regarding getline. It might have caused annoying bugs in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no direct way to say "get back to the start of the last line". However, you can get back to a position you kept by using `std::istream::tellg()`. That is, before reading a line you'd use `tellg()` and then `seekg()` to get back to the position.

However, calling the seek functions frequently is fairly expensive, i.e., I would look at removing the requirement to read lines again.

Comment: Thanks. Efficiency isn't my immediate concern, but I'll try to look into some other means of doing it later. Right now my main focus is just getting something that works.

Comment: I need to read characters from a 40gb file in a function until I hit a characters (delimiter characters) that the function should not read. Is using peek() less expensive or tellg() seekg() to mark the previous character position, which I need to return to? I guess the most efficient would be to not use any of this and just return the extra read character.

Comment: @BehroozKarjoo: using `peek()` is fairly cheap. Essentially it does `return this->gptr() != this->egptr()? *this->gptr(): this->underflow();` (it properly expands the `char` into an `int`, though). Assuming the stream is buffered this is a pointer conparison and a dereference. A `peek()` call does a lot more work.

Answer (score 4):

Store fstream position in the file (look at documentation).

Read line.

If condition happens - go to stored position in the file.

You need this:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg